# Excluding Fields in Django Class Based Views Not Working

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Boy, it feels like I've tried EVERYTHING here, and I just can't get this form to render properly (e.g. with a subset of fields). Here's the relevant items (extra items removed):

models.py:

```
class Response(models.Model):
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)

class ResponseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Response
        fields = ['question']
```

views.py:

```
class ResponseCreate(CreateView):
    model = Response
    fields = ['question']
```

response_form.html:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

I've read every bit of docs, and they suggest using `exclude`, `excludes`, `field`, `fields` in permutations of tuple, or list, and no matter what the "public" field seems to show up **every time**! Thoughts?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you add a comma in your form, `fields = ['question',]`, does that change things?

Comment: @ScottWoodall That would make a difference only for tuple type, not list

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you need to specify `form_class` on your view:

```
class ResponseCreate(CreateView):
    model = Response
    form_class = ResponseForm
```

Answer (score 0):

Just I want to mention that you don't really need a ModelForm to be created separately.

> Generic views really shine when working with models. These generic
>   views will automatically create aModelForm, so long as they can work
>   out which model class to use

You can just use this.

```
class Response(models.Model):
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', blank=True)

class ResponseCreate(CreateView):
    model = Response
    fields = ['question']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exclude` field in your class form:

```
class ResponseForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Response
        exclude = ['field_to_exclude']

class ResponseCreate(CreateView):
    model = Response
    form_class = ResponseForm
```